# GLM Gamma family

Tags: generalized-linear-model, logarithm

```
Term                 Estimate Std. Error     T-value   Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)           5.04024   0.05426        92.9     <2e-16  
Classe Juvenil       -1.45409   0.06265       -23.21    <2e-16  
Complexidade Simples 1.022298   0.06265        16.33    <2e-16
```

How can I interpret this results?
In intercept I think I have two parameters (Class Adulto and Complexidade Complexo)

Answer (score 1):

The intercept is the estimated mean for someone who is a complex adult, whatever that means. You then add the coefficient for youth (juvenil) to get the estimated mean for complex youth, add the coefficient for simple (simples) to get the estimated mean for simple adult, add both to get simple youth.

If you are modelling on the log scale (which you do not state) then those means are on the log scale and you may need to exponentiate them if you want to move back on to the raw scale.